# console error trying to install mapping software for ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, console

I am following this guide [here](http://www.gisnotes.com/wordpress/2010/08/iphone-dev-note-21-route-me-offline-mapping-from-database/)

Route-Me Offline Mapping from Database

I am on step 1 where I am installing the app that I will use to capture the maptiles for my ios map.. however I am reciving an error when I execute the last line

```
make install
```

generates this error in my console

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/Library/Perl/5.12/Geo/OSM'
mkdir /Library/Perl/5.12/Geo: Permission denied at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 494

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
```

I am not sure what this error means or how to fix it as I don't normally play around in the console.. but in order to achieve the out come I would like with my app I need some help figuring this out.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: omg.. thanks a ton.. I dont know mac terminal very well.. worked perfectly.. thanks a bunch.

Comment: OK - I have answered this formally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a permissions problem.  You can give yourself temporary root access using the `sudo` command ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html)).

Try the following:

```
$ sudo make install
```